# Readin lines from a txt file to a vector then passing it to another vector to split the lines, using a comma as the delimiter

Tags: c++, parsing, vector

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of an, outside the main(), vector. I'm trying to declare an array then have that array be passed to the outside split vector, once all lines are pushed back to vector declared in main. My issue is understanding how to pass the lines read in from the txt file to the split vector to be split up, and then return the value after the 4th comma to the original vector in the main method.

```
vector<string> split(const string& s, const string& delim) {
const bool keep_empty = true;
vector<string> result;
if (delim.empty()) {
    result.push_back(s);
    return result;
}
string::const_iterator substart = s.begin(), subend;
while (true) {
    subend = search(substart, s.end(), delim.begin(), delim.end());
    string temp(substart, subend);
    if (keep_empty || !temp.empty()) {
        result.push_back(temp);
    }
    if (subend == s.end()) {
        break;
    }
    substart = subend + delim.size();
}
return result;
}


void binary(vector<string> &airPort);
void Linear_Search(vector<string> &airPort);

int main()
{
vector<string> airPort;

string s;
int counts = 0;
string inp;
string total;
string cat = "cat";
string a, b, c, d, e;
char bs;

ifstream file("airports.dat");

if (!file.is_open()) {
    cout << "Filed to Open File!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

while (getline(file, s))
{
    istringstream ls(s);


                airPort.push_back(s);

}

vector<string> airPort = split(",", s);  //trying to pass the lines in 
                                              the airPort vector to be 
                                              split up
```

In the end Im trying to get it to where the airPort vector will be updated with only the values after the 4th comma, so the rest of the program may use that updated vector.

Comment: `split(",", s);` should be `split(s, ",");`. The first parameter is the string and the second the delimiter.

Comment: okay, how would I pass the vector containing the lines from the txt file the? vector<string> planeAir = split(s, ",");    -- Something like this?